# How to restrict number of characters that can be entered in HTML5 number input field on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile, input

It seems that neither of the "maxlength", "min" or "max" HTML attributes have the desired effect on iPhone  for the following markup:

```
 <input type="number" maxlength="2" min="0" max="99"/>
```

Instead of limiting the number of digits or the value of the number entered, the number is just left as it was typed in on iPhone 4. This markup works on most other phones we tested.

What gives?

Any workarounds?

If it is important to the solution, we use jQuery mobile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Example

**JS**

```js
function limit(element)
{
    var max_chars = 2;
         
    if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);">
```

If you are using jQuery you can tidy up the JavaScript a little:

**JS**

```js
var max_chars = 2;
    
$('#input').keydown( function(e){
    if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
    }
});
    
$('#input').keyup( function(e){
    if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" id="input">
```

Comment: Hi! This method is working fine, if I restrict user up to 1/2/3 characters, but as soon as I go to the limit of 4 or above, the solution breaks. I guess the problem is because of addition of ',' in the number field, but not sure. Can you please check this solution for 4 or more characters.

Comment: Sadly, I ended up relying on javascript/jQuery for this. I couldn't use type="range" because that has a different semantic.

Comment: Not on keydown : else no copy/paste

Comment: Use `substring()` instead of `substr()`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this code:

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="limitKeypress(event,this.value,2)"/>
```

and js code:

```
function limitKeypress(event, value, maxLength) {
    if (value != undefined && value.toString().length >= maxLength) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Buddy @Behnam Btw  Why we need  maxlength="2" min="0" max="99" here ...?? With out them it Works Fine  i guess :)

Comment: maxlength attr do not work in input with type="number"

Answer (score 3):

Another option with jQuery, but onkeypress event... ;)

```
$("input[type=number]").on('keypress',function(e) { 
    var $that = $(this),
    maxlength = $that.attr('maxlength')
    if($.isNumeric(maxlength)){
        if($that.val().length == maxlength) { e.preventDefault(); return; }

        $that.val($that.val().substr(0, maxlength));
    };
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength), `maxlength` is not used for `number`s. Have you tried just:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" />
```

OR

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="99" />
```

Comment: late to the game but how did this get 4 upvotes? deffo doesn't work

Comment: @TheWalrus but it does.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out, it works for me;

[Is there a minlength validation attribute in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5)

Comment: pattern=".{4,4}" : Great

Answer (score 1):

as Andrew said you need to change the type to range, beside that you are going to have problems with IE and FF and probably old ipad browser because that's from HTML 5, and it's a "Kind New".  Take a look to this person who tried the range with JS,
[Specify range of numbers to input in number field using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193278/specify-range-of-numbers-to-input-in-number-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to check how many characters are in the box and if there are too many, remove one:
http://www.webcodingtech.com/javascript/limit-input-text.php

Answer (score 1):

Here a more optimized jQuery version that caches the selectors.
It also uses the maxlength attribute that is not supported by input type number.

```
// limits the input based on the maxlength attribute, this is by default no supported by input type number
$("input[type=number]").on('keydown keyup',function(){ 
    var $that = $(this),
    maxlength = $that.attr('maxlength')
    if($.isNumeric(maxlength)){
        $that.val($that.val().substr(0, maxlength));
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use input event listener

```
<input type="text" 
    id="storeName"
    name="store_name" 
    class="store_name"
    placeholder="store name" 
    x-moz-errormessage="This field should not be left blank." 
    maxlength="500" required>   
<span id="storeNameCounter" class="store_name_counter">0/50</span>  

var storeName = document.getElementById('storeName')
var storeNameCounter = document.getElementById('storeNameCounter')       
    storeName.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
        var max_chars = 50         
        if(event.target.value.length > max_chars) {
        event.target.value = event.target.value.substr(0, max_chars)
        }
        storeNameCounter.innerHTML = `${event.target.value.length}/50`       
    })
```

Comment: By far the best answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is one year old, but I don't prefer the selected answer. Because the way it works is that it shows the character that is typed and then removes it.

In contrast I will propose another way which is similar to Will's, it is just better in the way that it prevents the character from being shown. Also I've added an `else if` block to check if the character is a number and then it is a good function to validate the number fields.

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" onkeydown="limit(this);">
```

**JS**

```
function limit(element)
{
    var max_chars = 2;
    if (arguments[1].char !== "\b" && arguments[1].key !== "Left" && arguments[1].key !== "Right") {
        if (element.value.length >= max_chars) {
            return false;
        } else if (isNaN(arguments[1].char)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Tripex answer optimized for allowing delete key, works when typing and on paste.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#your_element", function(e) {
    var $that = $(this),
    maxlength = $that.attr('maxlength');
    if ($.isNumeric(maxlength)){
        if($that.val().length === maxlength) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // If keyCode is not delete key 
            if (e.keyCode !== 64) {
                return;
            }
        }
        $that.val($that.val().substr(0, maxlength));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using jQuery:

**JS**

```
function maxlength(event)
{
    const ele = event.target;
    const maxlength = ele.maxLength;
    const value = ele.value;
    if (event.type == 'keypress')
    {
        if (value.length >= maxlength)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    else if (event.type == 'keyup')
    {
        if (value.length > maxlength)
        {
            ele.value = value.substring(0, maxlength);
        }
    }
}

$('input[type=number][maxlength]').on('keypress keyup', maxlength);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" maxlength="2">
```