# dynamically count textarea symbols in a simple input

Tags: javascript

Good day everyone
I have a simple textarea on a page,and I need to dynamically count number of symbols, show how much is left under the form,and limit number of characters should be 350.
Thanks in advance.
What i exactly need is to display how many symbols are left to type

```js
function limit(element)
{
    var max_chars = 350;

    if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
    }
}
```

```html
 <textarea onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);"></textarea>
```

Comment: And what is the question? What have you tried doing so far and where are the problems with it? So far you are asking us to write code for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841363/how-to-restrict-number-of-characters-that-can-be-entered-in-html5-number-input-f

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution,
just display the leftCharacters in a placeholder;

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      var $textarea = $('textarea');
      var $input = $('input[name="spaces"]');
      var maxLength = $textarea.attr('maxlength');
      $input.val(maxLength);

      $textarea.on('input', function() {
        var currentLength = $textarea.val().length;
        var leftCharacters = (maxLength - currentLength);
        $input.val(leftCharacters);
        });
    });

</script>

<textarea name=test" maxlength="350"></textarea>
<input name="spaces" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var max_chars = 5;
var charsLeftDisplay = document.getElementById("charsLeft");

function limit(element) {
  if (element.value.length > max_chars) {
    element.value = element.value.slice(0, -1);
    return false;
  }
  charsLeftDisplay.innerHTML = (max_chars - element.value.length) + " characters left...";
}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="limit(this)"></textarea>
<p id="charsLeft"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be to use JQuery

here's the html

```
<textarea id="textareaID" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="50"></textarea>

<p id="numberOfChars"><strong>Character typed:</strong> 0</p>
<p><strong>Max Character:</strong> 50</p>
```

and here's the jquery code

```
$('#textareaID').bind('input propertychange', function() {
      if(this.value.length){
        $("#numberOfChars").html("<strong>Character typed:</strong> "+this.value.length);
      }
});
```

and here's a working fiddle as well https://jsfiddle.net/Visrozar/zbw7j64j/

Answer (score 0):

This solution really works very well:

1 - Insert a div with id="textarea_count" for example in the place you want to show remaining characters, in your HTML file, near your textarea element (above or under):

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="DescCompetencia" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <textarea asp-for="DescCompetencia" class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="DescCompetencia" class="text-danger"></span>
            <div id="textarea_count"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

2 - Insert in your javascript file or after /html element in the page you are editing the textarea element:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var text_max =  500; //change by your max desired characters
var text_min = 7; //change to your min desired characters (or to zero, if field can be blank))
if ($('#DescCompetencia').length) {
    var texto_disponivel = text_max - $('#DescCompetencia').val().length;
}
$('#textarea_count').html(texto_disponivel + ' caracteres disponíveis para digitar');
$('#DescCompetencia').keyup(function () {
    var text_length = $('#DescCompetencia').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    if (text_length <= text_min) { 
        $('#textarea_count').html(text_remaining + ' caracteres remanescentes. Digite ' + text_min + ' ou mais caracteres.');
    }
    else {
        $('#textarea_count').html(text_remaining + ' caracteres remanescentes');
    }
});    });
```

**Must** have Jquery **already loaded** before calling the above function.